# Specific line in text file not deleted properly - Pointer and File-Handling

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, file-handling

I have this program where I can input the number of students, input their names, and their corresponding grades for prelims, midterms, and finals. it has 4 functions which are to write a record, view the record, read file saved, and delete a specific record.

This program is a simple example of pointer and file handling.

Here is my source code (though I'm just going to put the write and delete function since this is only where my problem is):

```
FILE *fp;
char ch[100], choice, c, file_name[50], studentName[20];
int  i, numberOfStudents;
int prelims, midterms, finals;
float averageScores, rating;

void getScore(char *studentName, int *prelims, int *midterms, int *finals);
float rate(float averageScores);
float average(int prelims, int midterms, int finals);

void write()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n Enter the number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &numberOfStudents);

    FILE *fp;

    fp = (fopen("studentRecord.txt", "a"));

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fp, "\n \n Name \t \t Prelims \t Midterms \t Finals \t Average \t Rating \n");
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; ++i)
    {
        printf("\n Student No. %d ", i + 1);
        getScore(studentName, &prelims, &midterms, &finals);
        averageScores = average(prelims, midterms, finals);
        rating = rate(averageScores);

        fprintf(fp, " %d.) %s \t %d \t \t %d \t \t %d \t \t %.2f \t \t %.2f \n", i + 1, studentName, prelims, midterms, finals, averageScores, rating);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n \n File studentRecord.txt is saved!");
    getch();
    view();
}

void getScore(char *studentName, int *prelims, int *midterms, int *finals)
{
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", studentName);

    printf("\n \t Prelims: ");
    scanf("%d", prelims);

    printf("\n \t Midterms: ");
    scanf("%d", midterms);

    printf("\n \t Finals: ");
    scanf("%d", finals);
}

void del()
{
    system("cls");
    int deleteLine, temp = 1;
    char chr;
    FILE *fpo;
    FILE *fp2;

    printf("\n Enter the file name: ");
    scanf("%s", file_name);

    // Opens file in read mode
    fpo = fopen(file_name, "r");
    chr = getc(fpo);

    while (chr != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", chr);
        chr = getc(fpo);
    }

    rewind(fpo);
    printf("\n Enter line number to be deleted: ");
    scanf("%d", &deleteLine);

    // Open new file in write mode
    fp2 = fopen("temp.txt", "w");

    chr = 'A';

    while (chr != EOF)
    {
        chr = getc(fpo);

        if (temp != deleteLine)
        {
            putc(chr, fp2);
        }
        if (chr == '\n')
        {
            temp++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fpo);
    fclose(fp2);
    remove(file_name);
    rename("temp.txt", file_name);

    printf("\n Number line deleted!");

    fpo = fopen(file_name, "r");
    chr = getc(fpo);

    while (chr != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", ch);
        chr = getc(fpo);
    }
    fclose(fpo);
    getch();
    main();
}
```

Whenever I enter a specific line to be deleted, it does not delete it but rather deletes the first line in the file. Here's an example:

[image: example_1]

[image]

Can anyone point out where I'm doing it wrong? I have been trying multiple methods of deleting a specific line in  a text file but none seems to work.

Comment: 'char chr;' cannot hold EOF.  Use int.

Comment: and for `chr = 'A';` the `'A'` has type `int` too.